# Google Apps-Script - How to lock a range of data using today's date and reference date

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to lock a row of data after they have been filled in using the date as a reference. Every time a data is captured the date would be automatically logged in column A of the google sheet. Using that logged date as a reference and comparing it with today's date. If the difference is 4 days the row would be locked and would not be able to be edited.

Comment: This can be achieved using [`Range.protect()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect()), I can't give you much more information as you have no sample code to work from.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You can lock ranges of a Google Sheet from being edited with the Range.protect() method.*

#### Example Code:

You need to create a Protection range by using the `Range.protect()` method which defines the range you need. As per the Apps Script example:

```js
function doProtections() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = ss.getRange('A1:Z1'); // Example of protecting Row 1
  var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Protected range name');

  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false); 
  }
}
```

You can then create an [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) which runs each day, comparing the current date with the date in the cell you need:

```js
function runEachDay() {
  var today = new Date()
  var dateToCheckAgainst = new Date(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange('A1').getValue())

  if (today.getTime() - dateToCheckAgainst.getTime() > 345600000) {
    doProtections();
  }
}
```

**Note:** The comparison to `345600000` is a Unix time - 345600000ms equals 4 days, so if more than 4 days have passed since the date in the cell you are checking (in my example function, A1), then the code will run.

#### References:

- [Class `Protection`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)
- [Class `Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html)

  - [`.protect()` method of Class `Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#protect)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Comment: When running the trigger function runEachDay, TypeError: Cannot find function getSheets in object function getActiveSpreadsheet() {/* */}. (line 3, file "Run each day").    The line, var dateToCheckAgainst = new Date(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange('A2:A')),

Comment: @Jon `getActiveSpreadsheet() ` is a function and needs parentheses

Comment: thanks for that.

 function runEachDay() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dateToCheckAgainst = new Date(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange('A1'));
  var a = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C1");
  var b = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("D1");
  a.setValue(today)
  b.setValue(dateToCheckAgainst)

  if (today.getTime() - dateToCheckAgainst.getTime() > 345600000) {
    doProtections();
  }
}



var dateToCheckAgainst does not pick up the date that is in cell A1(eg, 09/22/2019). The output of dateToCheckAgainst is 1/1/1970 7:30:00

Comment: @Jon `var dateToCheckAgainst = new Date(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange('A1'));` should be `var dateToCheckAgainst = new Date(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange('A1').getValue());`.